# "Speeding time up" vs "speeding up time."

Tags: phrase-choice

There are other examples, like "bringing up the topic" vs "bringing the topic up." What's the difference?

Example sentence:

> She wished she could speed up time/speed time up.

[speed up time](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=m23HW6HcL4mz8QWGx6_gDQ&q=%22speed%20up%20time%22&oq=%22speed%20up%20time%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11679.12843.0.13046.7.7.0.0.0.0.95.345.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.QJDOU1CmlJg)

[speed time up](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=im3HW66qKIyw8QXdgqyABA&q=%22speed%20time%20up%22&oq=%22speed%20time%20up%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15960.16237.0.16582.3.3.0.0.0.0.55.139.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.C9f5tZM6kp8)

I found both instances on Google Books, so I'm more  and more confused.

Comment: Most of these are personal choice.  It's good style to keep phrasal verbs like "bring up" together, but it's not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain rules govern phrasal verbs. When the direct object is a pronoun the pattern is:

`verb + pronoun + particle`

but when the direct object is a noun the pattern can be

`verb + noun + particle`

or

`verb + particle + noun`

> C'mon, what's the combination to the safe? Cough it up! <sup>OK</sup>
>
> C'mon, what's the combination to the safe? Cough up it! <sup>Not OK</sup>
>
> C'mon, cough up the combination to the safe!  <sup>OK</sup>
>
> C'mon, you'd better cough the combination up. <sup>OK</sup>

Comment: Superficially it does *seem* to be that the only difference is ***pronouns*** can only be placed *between* the verb and the particle / preposition. But I think there are a couple more relevant points. 1) If the noun (non-pronoun) is actually a *noun phrase*, the longer it is the less likely we are to put put it *inside* the "phrasal verb". 2) There can be a difference in implication between, say, *If the jury returns a guilty verdict, they'll lock John up* and *...they'll lock up John* (where the second version more strongly implies *lock John up rather than lock someone else up*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "the longer it is the less likely we are to put put it inside the "phrasal verb." You mean "up" will less likely to go at the end? Because the verb and up will be too separated from each other, and therefore sound strange?

Comment: @alexchenco: Yes. I mean *You'd better cough **the money for your daughter's wedding to my son next week** up,* for example, is an unlikely phrasing - and that's at least *partly* because there's too much "distance" between the two halves of the phrasal verb ***cough up***. In cases where you *do* encounter a "longish" interpolated noun phrase like that, you'll often find that it's spoken noticeably faster than normal, because the speaker knows he's presenting his audience with an utterance that's a bit tricky to parse on the fly.